# Layout of columns which automatically fill fixed width container vertically?

Tags: html, css, layout

I've got elements with different heights but fixed width in a container element. When I set the elements to `inline-block`, the columns fill up automatically, but horizontally, like this. Please notice the numbers, indicating an element.

```
1## 2## 3##
### ### ###
###     ###
        ###
4## 5## 6##
### ### ###
###
7## 8## 9##
### ### ###
        ###
```

What I'd like is to have them fill up vertically too, like this.

```
1## 2## 3##
### ### ###
### 5## ###
4## ### ###
### 8## 6##
### ### ###
7##     9##
###     ###
        ###
```

And lets assume the width of the container element is increased.

```
1## 2## 3## 4##
### ### ### ###
### 6## ### ###
5## ### ### 8##
###     7## ###
9##     ###
###
###
```

Is there any way to do this with just HTML and CSS?

Comment: AFAIK With just html & css I dont think this can be achieved ... we will have to use js/jquery

Answer (score 2):

CSS layouts don't support this. You'll have to use a Javascript layout tool like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to achieve the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS3 Columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) ([Compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#search=column)) to do this. For example:

```
ol {
    list-style: decimal outside;

    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

The multi-column module is not supported in IE9 (but it will be in IE10). To avoid the child elements being split up you need the [`break-inside`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#break-before-break-after-break-inside) property:

```
ol li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Unfortunately this is not supported in Firefox ([Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549114)).

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4BNm/2/

Comment: Columns won't work in the source order that's needed: they fill down first, not across first.

Comment: @AndrewVit No it wouldn't, you're right. This is about the closest you can do with current CSS technology though